# How to index pdf files from HDFS to Solr

Tags: hadoop, pdf, solr, hdfs

I am new to Apache solr
I have a requirement in my project where I have to upload pdf documents from HDFS to Solr and from there I want to get using Solr rest API's.
I have total 40k pdf documents in my local file system, first I will push them to HDFS. But from there to Solr I really don't have any idea

**Another thing is while indexing into solr, i want to read some data from pdf document and index that data also into Solr.**
Example: I want extraxt candidate name, candidate location from pdf document and push them into solr schema which looks like,

```
name: "candidate_name"
location: "candidate_location"
document: "pdf_document"
```

I searched for this over the internet, but couldn't find the right solution

Comment: while indexing into solr. Apache Tika will take care to extract PDF content and index. But all page text content will be stored into one field.

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr+on+HDFS... https://developer.ibm.com/hadoop/blog/2016/01/01/indexing-hadoop-docs-solr/

Comment: Hi @AbhijitBashetti, the link which you have posted is showing 404 error. Anyways thanks for the reply.

Comment: @ShekarPatel : Its was working that day ...my bad...but yes time now you can refer the solr one... Here I add one more for you... https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/6389/solr-how-to-index-rich-text-document-put-in-hdfs.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using the https://github.com/lucidworks/hadoop-solr

You should try the DirectoryIngestMapper, it has Tika parsing, but you will have to customized it.